# Gaussian process for modeling multiple time series

Tags: regression, time-series, markov-process, gaussian-process

I'm dealing with a time series dataset which contains multiple tracks for a particle, (i.e. for different independent instances, a sensor is observing a particle, marking its position, for varying lengths of time). This is a dataset comprising of independent stacked time series of different lengths.

Can I apply a single gaussian process to do regression over this dataset? If so, how do I structure the input data? I am not interested in capturing seasonality effect, as the periodicity is actually an artifact of the data collection. Rather, I want to leverage the multiple tracks to fit a function that can estimate the behavior of the particle over a given trajectory.

Comment: Yes, but one needs to pick a Kernel that explains covariance structure. See one of the nicest introductions to Gaussian Processes from Ghahramani https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.372.2641&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: Thanks @MehmetSüzen for your comment. I reviewed the slides you linked, but I am not sure how they help me with the solving my problem. From my review of this and other articles, I am gathering that I need to align the tracks to a shared time maker, which is I can do. Beyond that, the problem is still vague to me. Can you explain more about what you mean by the kernel needs to explain the covariance structure?

Comment: One would need to choose a Kernel function and build a Covariance matrix. See pages 6-7 from Gharamani Slides). x* or x' are the points we would like to do prediction/smoothing for multi-dimentions and solve the equations for the Gaussian parameters $\mu^{*}$ and $\sigma^{*}$ (page 12 from Gharamani Slides).

Comment: Right, understood. I know that the critical part is estimating the covariance matrix via a kernel whose parameters are optimized during training. What I'm trying to understand is the structure of the training data. Since there are multiple tracks in the data, stacked vertically (ie. you have multiple multivariate entries for timepoints [0, 10]), will I be able to shove all those tracks in at once and the GP will learn to predict one trajectory, or do I need to do something else?

Comment: @MehmetSüzen Maybe the more appropriate question is can I tell the kernel that these tracks are independent? Will it learn that on its own?

Comment: Yes, advantage of GPs are covariance is learned.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130134/discussion-between-myselfesteem-and-mehmet-suzen).